# Help me verify my proof that FINITE is undecidable

Tags: undecidability

Is my proof that FINIT is undecidable correct?

FINITE= { ⟨M⟩ | M is a Turing machine that accepts only finitely many strings } is undecidable.

Answer:
To prove this we can use reduce to Halting Problem, which is a known to be undecidable problem.
to prove that FINITE is undecidable, assume for contradiction that there is a decider D for FINITE. This decider takes a TM  M and decides whether M accepts only finitely many strings.
And by using D, we can construct a Turing machine M′ to decide the HP
M′ takes as input a description of a Turing machine H and a string w.
M′ constructs a new Turing machine N as follows:
N on input x simulates H on w.
If H halts on w, then N accepts x.
If H does not halt on w, then N runs indefinitely.

Now, M′ uses the decider D on N. If D decides that N accepts only finitely many strings, it means H does not halt on w (since N doesn't accept any string if H doesn't halt). If D decides that N does not accept only finitely many strings, it means H halts on w (since N would accept all strings in this case).

Comment: We don't normally approve of "check my homework" questions. What is it that you're not sure about? Is there something specific about the proof you don't understand?

Comment: I am just not sure if my argument is correct. It is not for homework actually, I am just preparing for an exam and I am trying to see solve some problems from previous exams.

Comment: The proof looks good to me, except that it is a reduction **from** the halting problem and not **to** the halting problem. You designed a Turing machine with an oracle for FINITE that decides the halting problem.